# Timeout in Springboot with couchbase

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

We are creating a SpringBoot project (2.4.2) with couchbase (string-data-couchbase 4.1.3). When I try to make a query using REST I use a URL such as `http://COUCHDB_URL:8888/dtx-prod/_design/views/_view/view_country` (with the username and password already filled in) I get the correct results.
In my SpringBoot I adapted the example from [spring-data/couchbase documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration-java) from  to create the configuration class in Kotlin:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration

@Configuration
class CouchDBConfig : AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration() {

    override fun getConnectionString(): String = "couchbase://COUCHDB_URL:8888"

    override fun getUserName(): String = "USERNAME"

    override fun getPassword(): String = "PASSWORD"

    override fun getBucketName(): String = "dtx-prod"

}
```

However, when I run my application, I am not able to connect. These are the messages from log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)

2021-02-05 13:55:04.609  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.h.d.c.DtxCountriesApplicationKt      : Starting DtxCountriesApplicationKt using Java 11.0.9 on LPT-LE0467 with PID 41484 (C:\projects\dtx-backend\dtx-countries\target\classes started by ruclementeafonso in C:\projects\dtx-backend\dtx-countries)
2021-02-05 13:55:04.609  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.h.d.c.DtxCountriesApplicationKt      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-05 13:55:05.132  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Couchbase repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-05 13:55:05.145  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 12 ms. Found 0 Couchbase repository interfaces.
2021-02-05 13:55:05.148  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Couchbase repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-05 13:55:05.163  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14 ms. Found 1 Couchbase repository interfaces.
2
...
2021-02-05 13:55:05.686  INFO 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.core                       : [com.couchbase.core][CoreCreatedEvent] {"clientVersion":"3.0.10","clientGitHash":"a0a82dda","coreVersion":"2.0.11","coreGitHash":"a0a82dda","userAgent":"couchbase-java/3.0.10 (Windows 10 10.0 amd64; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.9+7-LTS)","maxNumRequestsInRetry":32768,"ioEnvironment":{"nativeIoEnabled":true,"eventLoopThreadCount":4,"eventLoopGroups":["NioEventLoopGroup"]},"ioConfig":{"captureTraffic":[],"mutationTokensEnabled":true,"networkResolution":"auto","dnsSrvEnabled":true,"tcpKeepAlivesEnabled":true,"tcpKeepAliveTimeMs":60000,"configPollIntervalMs":2500,"kvCircuitBreakerConfig":"disabled","queryCircuitBreakerConfig":"disabled","viewCircuitBreakerConfig":"disabled","searchCircuitBreakerConfig":"disabled","analyticsCircuitBreakerConfig":"disabled","managerCircuitBreakerConfig":"disabled","numKvConnections":1,"maxHttpConnections":12,"idleHttpConnectionTimeoutMs":4500,"configIdleRedialTimeoutMs":300000},"compressionConfig":{"enabled":true,"minRatio":0.83,"minSize":32},"securityConfig":{"tlsEnabled":false,"nativeTlsEnabled":true,"hasTrustCertificates":false,"trustManagerFactory":null},"timeoutConfig":{"kvMs":2500,"kvDurableMs":10000,"managementMs":75000,"queryMs":75000,"viewMs":75000,"searchMs":75000,"analyticsMs":75000,"connectMs":10000,"disconnectMs":10000},"loggerConfig":{"customLogger":null,"fallbackToConsole":false,"disableSlf4j":false,"loggerName":"CouchbaseLogger","diagnosticContextEnabled":false},"orphanReporterConfig":{"emitIntervalMs":10000,"sampleSize":10,"queueLength":1024},"thresholdRequestTracerConfig":{"emitIntervalMs":10000,"sampleSize":10,"queueLength":1024,"kvThresholdMs":500,"queryThresholdMs":1000,"searchThresholdMs":1000,"analyticsThresholdMs":1000,"viewThresholdMs":1000},"retryStrategy":"BestEffortRetryStrategy","requestTracer":"ThresholdRequestTracer"} {"coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","seedNodes":[{"address":"COUCHDB_URL","kvPort":8888}]}
2021-02-05 13:55:05.689  INFO 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.node                       : [com.couchbase.node][NodeConnectedEvent] Node connected {"coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","managerPort":"8091","remote":"COUCHDB_URL"}
... 
2021-02-05 13:55:06.188  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.h.d.c.DtxCountriesApplicationKt      : Started DtxCountriesApplicationKt in 1.628 seconds (JVM running for 2581.994)
2021-02-05 13:55:06.191  INFO 41484 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
2021-02-05 13:55:15.775  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][10s] Connect attempt 1 failed because of TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 10000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured) {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8888","type":"KV"}

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 10000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:279) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:418) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:119) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:15.777  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.core                       : [com.couchbase.core][InitGlobalConfigFailedEvent][10s] Initializing the global config failed: UNKNOWN {"coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005"}

com.couchbase.client.core.error.ConfigException: Caught exception while loading global config.
    at com.couchbase.client.core.config.loader.GlobalLoader.lambda$load$3(GlobalLoader.java:70) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1836) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:315) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:196) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onError(FluxDoFinally.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.Reactor$SilentMonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(Reactor.java:175) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.msg.BaseRequest.cancel(BaseRequest.java:168) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.Timer.lambda$register$2(Timer.java:157) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:672) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:747) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:472) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.error.UnambiguousTimeoutException: CarrierGlobalConfigRequest, Reason: TIMEOUT
    at com.couchbase.client.core.msg.BaseRequest.cancel(BaseRequest.java:163) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
2021-02-05 13:55:15.778  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][10s] Connect attempt 1 failed because of TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 10000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured) {"bucket":"dtx-prod","circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8888","type":"KV"}

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 10000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:279) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:418) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:119) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:18.196  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][2427ms] Connect attempt 1 failed because of AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091 {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8091","type":"MANAGER"}

com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:20.623  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][2420ms] Connect attempt 1 failed because of AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091 {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8091","type":"MANAGER"}

com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:20.624  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][2431ms] Connect attempt 2 failed because of AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091 {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8091","type":"MANAGER"}

com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:23.049  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][2423ms] Connect attempt 1 failed because of AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091 {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8091","type":"MANAGER"}

com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:23.051  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][2420ms] Connect attempt 2 failed because of AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091 {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8091","type":"MANAGER"}

com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:23.153  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][2421ms] Connect attempt 3 failed because of AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091 {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8091","type":"MANAGER"}

com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-05 13:55:25.476  WARN 41484 --- [      cb-events] com.couchbase.endpoint                   : [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][2424ms] Connect attempt 1 failed because of AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091 {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xc1a6ce3800000005","remote":"COUCHDB_URL:8091","type":"MANAGER"}

com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /COUCHDB_URL:8091
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Apparently, it tries to connect to the server, waits for 10 seconds to get an answer and tries to connect using another port.

I already tried to change the return from `CouchDBConfig.getConnectionString()` to `COUCHDB_URL:8888` (without `couchbase` protocol) but I got the same error.
I also tried `http://COUCHDB_URL:8888` but this time the library rejects http protocol. The message is `com.couchbase.client.core.error.CouchbaseException: Could not parse Scheme of connection string: http://COUCHDB_URL:8888`.

So, What is missing here? Why is there this delay and timeout to connect with server if when I use REST it is almost immediate.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?